# Opening a link via javascript code

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple HTML/javascript question. I have a button and a link. My HTML looks like this :

```
<a id="a1" href="https://www.facebook.com/"> </a>
<input type="button">
```

How can I open the link by clicking the button? I know I can just type a function in javascript like

```
function f1() {
    location = document.getElementById("a1").href;
}
```

and put it in the onclick attribute of the button but I want the link to be opened in a new tab. Can anyone tell me how to do this via javaScript/HTML?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `window.open`:

```
function f1() {
    window.open(document.getElementById("a1").href, "_blank");
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexChariz/obd122fd/9/)

**Reference**

[window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open)

Answer (score 1):

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4eac4v15/2/)

```
function openwindow() {
    var a = document.getElementById("a1").href;
    window.open(a, '_blank');
}
```